# Requirements for constructor in interface

Tags: java, android, interface, constructor, enums

First, to be clear, I KNOW WHAT IS AN INTERFACE.

What I mean is, can I require the class which implement the interface to have a constructor mentioned in the interface?

As follows:

```
public interface IA {
    /*constructor requirement*/
    public IA(int, int, int, int, int, int, int);
}

public class A implements IA {
    /* Because I implements IA, I have to make this contructor */
    public A(int, int, int, int, int, int, int) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: The actual case is I m making a class with generic enum. I hope the enum comes with an object. So, this requires the constructor with specific parameter.

And direct "extends" is not allowed for enum

Comment: To be clear, I just want to know if there are any way by interface to force a class to GET A CONSTRUCTOR WITH SPECIFIC PARAMS

Answer (score 3):

Specifying a constructor in an interface is not allowed.  This shouldn't be allowed, because constructors aren't inherited.  If a superclass has a constructor `Superclass(int, int, int)`, then that does not force a subclass to have a constructor `Subclass(int, int, int)`.  So, interfaces shouldn't be able to force constructors either.

The [JLS, Section 9.1.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.1.4), states the only things that can exist within an interface body:]

> The body of an interface may declare members of the interface, that is, fields (§9.3), methods (§9.4), classes (§9.5), and interfaces (§9.5).
>
> ```
> InterfaceBody:
>     { InterfaceMemberDeclarationsopt }
>
> InterfaceMemberDeclarations:
>     InterfaceMemberDeclaration
>     InterfaceMemberDeclarations InterfaceMemberDeclaration
>
> InterfaceMemberDeclaration:
>     ConstantDeclaration
>     AbstractMethodDeclaration
>     ClassDeclaration 
>     InterfaceDeclaration
>     ;
> ```

This means that Java specifically disallows constructors in interfaces; the JLS does not list constructors in the list of things that can be members in an interface.

Comment: I dun think thats a valid reason. If I write an interface which requires "getClass()" method. Every object got a getClass method and no one need to write a new one to match the interface. The interface should be just ensure you do have it.

Comment: So, if Superclass(int, int, int) exists, nothing changed. but if some class, which do not have it, says to implement that interface, it should write a Someclass(int, int, int)

Comment: You could force a class to have a `getClass()` method with an interface, but that's a method, not a constructor, and constructors aren't inherited.  The closest you could get is to force a subclass constructor to _call_ a superclass constructor by making the only constructor in `Superclass` take all your required arguments.

Comment: If you have a Superclass(int, int, int) that does not have a default constructor and only has the Superclass(int, int, int) constructor, then your subclasses, SomeClass, will have to call that constructor. This will guarantee that Superclass still gets the arguments it needs. However, SomeClass, does not HAVE to implement a Someclass(int, int, int) constructor. It can pass in the values to Superclass(int, int, int) in whatever way is appropriate for SomeClass, for example using default values.

Comment: mdewitt What I mean is that SomeClass does not have any inheritance with SuperClass, but it seems that you got my idea. That's what I mean. And SomeClass is another class which does not have SomeClass(int,int,int) throughout the whole superclasses.

Comment: To be clear, I just want to know if there are any way by interface to force a class to GET A CONSTRUCTOR WITH SPECIFIC PARAMS. :P

Comment: No, there is not. An interface can specify which methods a class must implement, but an interface can have no say in how the class implements those methods from the interface. An interface can definitely not say how classes that do not implement the interface implement anything. If a class needs to call a specific constructor, then the class should be designed to have any necessary arguments that constructor needs.

Comment: Sigh, but the point is Enum is not allowed for a direct extend. I cant make an abstract class or what to do that

Comment: I think you need to rethink your design. If you ask a different question with more details about your design, it might be easier to help you. But I believe @rgettman's answer here answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

No. You might be able to do something like that with a builder.

Answer (score 0):

In its most common form, an interface is a group of related methods with empty bodies. A bicycle's behavior, if specified as an interface, might appear as follows:

```
interface Bicycle {

    //  wheel revolutions per minute
    void changeCadence(int newValue);

    void changeGear(int newValue);

    void speedUp(int increment);

    void applyBrakes(int decrement);
}
```

To implement this interface, the name of your class would change (to a particular brand of bicycle, for example, such as ACMEBicycle), and you'd use the implements keyword in the class declaration:

```
class ACMEBicycle implements Bicycle {

    // remainder of this class 
    // implemented all methods of interface
}
```

Interface does not have constructors,  at all and if you have methods in the interface then you have to implement all the methods in your class otherwise mark you class which is implementing the interface as abstract

This is the abstract method in the interface not constructor

```
public IA(int, int, int, int, int, int, int);
```